# What is Laplace transform of $\frac{e^{-t}}t \sin3t\sin2t$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, laplacian

What is Laplace of :

> $$\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{e^{-t}}t\sin3t\sin2t\right)$$

I m trying to use first shifting property and not able to get correct answer.

Comment: @Isham what is answer?

Comment: I posted some hints to get the transform you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{e^{-t}}{t} \sin(3t) \sin(2t) = \frac{e^{-t}}{2t}\cos(t) - \frac{e^{-t}}{2t}\cos(5t)$$
Let $f(t) = e^{-t}\cos(t)$ and $g(t) = e^{-t}\cos(5t)$, we get
$$\frac{e^{-t}}{t} \sin(3t) \sin(2t) =\frac{1}{2} (\frac{f(t)}{t} -\frac{g(t)}{t})$$
Using the property that 
$$L(\frac{f(t)}{t}) = \int\limits_s^{\infty} F(u) \ du$$ we get
$$L(\frac{e^{-t}}{t} \sin(3t) \sin(2t)) = \frac{1}{2}[\int\limits_s^{\infty} F(u) \ du  - \int\limits_s^{\infty} G(u) \ du]$$
where $F(s),G(s)$ are Laplace Transforms of $f(t),g(t)$. 
Using $L(e^{-at}\cos( wt) ) = \frac{s+a}{(s+a)^2 + w^2}$, we can say
$$F(u) = \frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2 + 1} $$
$$G(u) = \frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2 + 25} $$
Computing the integrals:
$$\int\limits_s^{\infty} F(u) \ du = \int\limits_s^{\infty}  \frac{u+1}{(u+1)^2 + 1} \ d u = \frac{1}{2}[\lim_{u \rightarrow \infty} \ln ((u+1)^2 + 1) -  \ln ((s+1)^2 + 1)]$$
$$\int\limits_s^{\infty} G(u) \ du = \int\limits_s^{\infty}  \frac{u+1}{(u+1)^2 + 25} \ d u = \frac{1}{2}[\lim_{u \rightarrow \infty} \ln ((u+1)^2 + 25) -  \ln ((s+1)^2 + 25)]$$
Denote the limits as $A,B$, then:
$$L(\frac{e^{-t}}{t} \sin(3t) \sin(2t)) = \frac{1}{4}[\ln ((s+1)^2 + 25)-\ln ((s+1)^2 + 1) + A-B]$$
which is
$$L(\frac{e^{-t}}{t} \sin(3t) \sin(2t)) = \frac{1}{4}[\ln \frac{(s+1)^2 + 25}{(s+1)^2 + 1} + \lim_{u \rightarrow \infty} \ln \frac{(u+1)^2 + 25}{(u+1)^2 + 1}] = \frac{1}{4}\ln \frac{(s+1)^2 + 25}{(s+1)^2 + 1}$$

Answer (score 0):

***Hint***

You can use 
$$\sin(a) \sin(b)=\frac 12( \cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b))$$
$$\sin(3t) \sin(2t)=\frac 12( \cos(t)-\cos(5t))$$
Then use the formula
$$\mathcal{L} \left(\frac {f(t)}t\right )=\int_s^\infty F(u)du$$
I finally got this
$$F(s)=\frac 14 \ln \left (\frac {s^2+2s+26}{s^2+2s+2}  \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

With integration of the formula ${\cal L}\left(e^{ct}\right)=\dfrac{1}{s-c}$ respect to $c$ we find
$${\cal L}\left(\dfrac{e^{ct}}{t}\right)=\ln\dfrac{1}{s-c}$$
then by $\sin\alpha=\dfrac{e^{i\alpha}-e^{-i\alpha}}{2i}$ we write
\begin{align}
{\cal L}\left(\dfrac{e^{-t}\sin3t\sin2t}{t}\right)
&= -\dfrac14{\cal L}\left(\dfrac{e^{(5i-1)t}-e^{(-i-1)t}-e^{(i-1)t}+e^{(-5i-1)t}}{t}\right)\\
&= -\dfrac14{\cal L}\left(\ln\dfrac{1}{s-(5i-1)}-\ln\dfrac{1}{s-(-i-1)}-\ln\dfrac{1}{s-(i-1)}+\ln\dfrac{1}{s-(-5i-1)}\right)\\
&= \color{blue}{-\dfrac14\ln\dfrac{(s+1)^2+1}{(s+1)^2+25}}
\end{align}

Comment: further can we put   s=1 in final answer?

Comment: For what purpose? it's a function of $s$.

Comment: answer will be -1/4 ln(5/29)?is it right?

Comment: I think it is a part of a problem.